# SQL2008 evaluation period

Tags: sql-server-2008, evaluation

I install a sql2008 enterprise evaluation edition instance with evaluation license. is there any way to get how many days are left before expires the evaluation period ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: Server Management Studio then select "Help" > Under about.